# Agda: Why does the compiler demand Set_1, not Set in a data definition?

Tags: set, agda

Tried to define a simple set product in Agda 2.6.4:

```
module Bool where
open import Function using (id ; const ; _∘_ ; _$_ )
open import Agda.Primitive

variable
  a : Level
  A B C : Set

data _×_ : Set -> Set -> Set where -- conjunction
   _,_ : A -> B -> A × B
```

Which yields the following error:

```
 C:\Users\...\Bool.agda:11,4-7
Set₁ is not less or equal than Set
when checking that the type Set of an argument to the constructor
_,_ fits in the sort Set of the datatype.
Note: this argument is forced by the indices of _,_, so this
definition would be allowed under --large-indices.
```

I have no idea what went wrong. The product of two sets must be a `Set`, not `Set₁`. But for some reason the following compiles just fine (I replaced `Set -> Set -> Set` with `Set -> Set -> Set₁`).

```
module Bool where
open import Function using (id ; const ; _∘_ ; _$_ )
open import Agda.Primitive

variable
  a : Level
  A B C : Set
  A₁ A₂ B₁ B₂ : Set a

data _×_ : Set -> Set -> Set₁ where -- conjunction
   _,_ : A -> B -> A × B

fst : A × B -> A
fst (x , x₁) = x

snd : A × B -> B
snd (x , x₁) = x₁
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more than a syntactic difference.
Your original definition had A and B as *indices* of the data type `_x_` while your new definition had A and B as *parameters*.

This makes a difference for the universe level of the data type, because in the first case the type `A x B` contains values of the form `_,_ {A} {B} a b` for `A, B : Set`, `a : A` and `b : B`.
In other words, values of the type `A x B` contain the types `A` and `B`, which is why Agda insists that the type must live in a larger universe.

When `A` and `B` are parameters, then the type `A x B` contains values of the form `_,_ a b`, i.e. the values do not "contain" the types `A` and `B`, which is why the type can live in the universe `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the syntax. The following did the trick:

```
data  _×_ (A B : Set) : Set  where -- conjunction
   _,_ : A -> B -> A × B
```